# Alpha to coverage in android gives transparent areas in some cases it shouldn't

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, glsl, opengl-es-2.0

I'm developing my own game engine for android with opengl es 2.0 and I want to have some planes with a texture that in some sites is transparent or translucent. This is because I'm using MSAA with GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_SAMPLE_ALPHA_TO_COVERAGE).
When I try to render something whose material hasn't an specular term like a lambert material I send to the shader a specular value of (0,0,0,0) with an alpha of 0.0 (last term).

In the fragment shader I have the next code:

```
vec4 specularMaterialTerm = vec4 (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0); /* El canal especular será NO opaco y negro hasta que se sobreescriban sus datos */
if (!Material.hasSpecularTexture){
    specularMaterialTerm = Material.specular;
}
else {
    specularMaterialTerm = texture2D(Material.specularTexture, outTextCoord);
}

specularReflection = attenuation * pow(NdotHV, (Material.shininess)) * vec4(lightSource.lightColor, 1.0) * specularMaterialTerm;
if (Material.hasSpecularTexture){ // premultiplicado por alpha en bitmapfactory de android
    specularReflection.rgb *= specularMaterialTerm.a;
}

if (diffuseMaterialTerm.a != 0.0){
    totalLightingColor = totalLightingColor + diffuseReflection;
}

if (specularMaterialTerm.a != 0.0) {
    totalLightingColor = totalLightingColor + vec4(vec3(specularReflection),1.0);
}
```

I can't understand why if even controlling when the alpha is 0.0 and not adding it's value with the line if (specularMaterialTerm.a != 0.0), the multisampling makes my not translucent textures to be translucent or transparent. In the example image I upload here the floor has not an specular term so its value in the shader is 0,0,0,0 (alpha 0) but has not translucent values in the diffuse texture and the sun rays texture has transparency in it's texture and also it hasn't specular term.

I hope you can understand what I want to mean. This is the screen capture:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhZ5z.jpg

EDIT:

I don't know if this has something to do, but this is my blending function:

```
GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_ONE, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Answer (score 0):

For alpha to coverage to kill samples the final output color written by the fragment shader (before blending) must have an alpha value of less than 1.0. Assuming 4x MSAA to kill everything the final alpha must be less than 0.25.

You can check which fragments are being impacted by alpha to coverage by modifying the end of your fragment shader to set all fragments with a non-1.0 alpha to, for example, (0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0) to show which areas are impacted by the alpha-to-coverage test. Any color will work as long as alpha is 1.0 ...

TBH the issue with your scene looks more like missing geometry (assuming you are talking about the big triangle patch missing on the floor). Which device / GPU are you using?

Comment: There is no missing geometry in the scene. If I disable alpha to coverage, the floor draws without transparence. I solved it, but I dont understand why was failling. In a fragment glsl method I use to compute the final color of a texel I init the variable I return this way: vec4 finalColor = vec4(0.0). Later I add the diffuse y the specular terms with finalColor = diffuseTerm + specularTerm. But the alpha was not being added and remains 0.0. If I put finalColor.a = diffuseColor.a + specularColor.a the problem is solved.

Comment: By the way I´m using an Adreno 305 device (Moto g 2014 version)

Comment: Well if you initialize alpha to 0.0 and then never update it, then alpha-to-coverage will clear the coverage mask of all of the samples. Totally transparent pixels = zero coverage. If you want to keep full coverage, initialize alpha value to 1.0.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As far as I know a call to texture2D(Material.specularTexture, outTextCoord) should initialize the alpha chanel, even if the texture has not it to 1.0, shouldn't it?

Comment: For unorm textures the texture call will return an alpha of 1.0 if the image doesn't have an alpha channel at all, otherwise the value in the texture is returned.